# Internal server error Maven web service (jersey-quickstart-grizzly template)

Tags: java, maven, jersey, grizzly

I have the following pom.xml file configuration. I'm new in Java and try to run a basic restful web service using Maven.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.test.rest</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-rest</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>test-rest</name>
    <dependencies>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-grizzly</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- uncomment this to get JSON support: -->
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            <version>1.19</version>
        </dependency>
       
        <!-- uncomment this to get Fastinfoset support:
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-fastinfoset</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        -->
        <!-- uncomment this to get ATOM support:
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-atom</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        -->
        <!-- uncomment this to get multipart MIME types support:
         <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        -->
           <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.grizzly</groupId>
            <artifactId>grizzly-servlet-webserver</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.45</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>10</source>
                    <target>10</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.test.rest.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <jersey-version>1.20-SNAPSHOT</jersey-version>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Everything setup, but when I  ran the local host in the browser it gave an "Internal Server" error.

Here is the error description

> Sep 29, 2023 9:52:26 PM com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig
> init INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the
> packages:   com.test.rest Sep 29, 2023 9:52:26 PM
> com.sun.grizzly.http.servlet.ServletAdapter doService SEVERE: service
> exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
> at jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.(ClassReader.java:170)
> at jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.(ClassReader.java:153)
> at jersey.repackaged.org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.(ClassReader.java:424)
> at com.sun.jersey.spi.scanning.AnnotationScannerListener.onProcess(AnnotationScannerListener.java:138)
> at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.uri.FileSchemeScanner$1.f(FileSchemeScanner.java:86)
> at com.sun.jersey.core.util.Closing.f(Closing.java:71)
> at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.uri.FileSchemeScanner.scanDirectory(FileSchemeScanner.java:83)
> at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.uri.FileSchemeScanner.scan(FileSchemeScanner.java:71)
> at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.PackageNamesScanner.scan(PackageNamesScanner.java:226)
> at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.scanning.PackageNamesScanner.scan(PackageNamesScanner.java:142)
> at com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig.init(ScanningResourceConfig.java:80)
> at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.init(PackagesResourceConfig.java:104)
> at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.(PackagesResourceConfig.java:78)
> at com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig.(PackagesResourceConfig.java:89)
> at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:696)
> at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.createResourceConfig(WebComponent.java:674)
> at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:205)
> at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:394)
> at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:577)
> at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:241)
> at com.sun.grizzly.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.loadServlet(ServletAdapter.java:486)
> at com.sun.grizzly.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.doService(ServletAdapter.java:425)
> at com.sun.grizzly.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.service(ServletAdapter.java:379)
> at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
> at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
> at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
> at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
> at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
> at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
> at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
> at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
> at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
> at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
> at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
> at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
> at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
> at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)

Used command to run project: "mvn -e compile exec:java"
I already googled about this error but not found any working solution.

Comment: Looks like the Jersey version is incompatible with the Java version you are using

Comment: Please stop using Jersey 1.x